# Can selection algorithm have a space complexity of O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, selection, space-complexity

I need to use the selection algorithm (with the median of medians version of it), but the space complexity of it is too high for me. Is there a way to reduce the space complexity to Ѳ(1)?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to find k-th order statistic?

Comment: How about quick select? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect It's constant space if you're able to re-order the input array. Otherwise it needs a copy to work on.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562256/why-is-the-median-of-medians-algorithm-described-as-using-o1-auxiliary-space , and specifically, the paper pointed out by @Stefan Pochmann